# Old crt tv help

Tags: tvs

my old portable crt television has this port on the back that looks like a headphone jack, but it's labeled ext ant. Can I connect a rf modulator to that port at all?

Thanks...
[image]

Comment: Try to focus your potato better and take another picture.  take a picture at a slight angle so we can see depth.

Comment: There was a really old atari/nintendo/turbo grafx era modulator/demodulator we had when I was little that had a fork connector for that screw terminal, and probably matches the earphone style connector as well.  Alas I can't find one online.  You may have to figure out the pinout for that jack and buy a plug to put on another mod/demod.

Comment: Does also say 12V after Ant?

Comment: Isn't "Ant" for "external antenna"?

Answer (score 2):

Typically they are used to extend the internal antenna if reception is bad but it should work.

Comment: But it's a 3.5 mm jack, I suppose there are adapters for it to fit into the modulator?